# XCode 4 Unable to Open Old Projects

Tags: xcode, macos

I just upgraded to XCode 4 and am now unable to view a number of my previous XCode 3 projects. When I launch the projects XCode opens, but it looks like this:

[image: No Files and No Editor]

Any way to tell what is going wrong? Any special logs I can look at? I don't get any warnings or errors appearing!

Comment: Can to create a new, sample Xcode 3 project that won't open in Xcode 4? Can you make any of your Xcode 3 projects that won't open in Xcode 4 available?

Comment: @ericgorr Yeah, I wish I could but non are open source unfortunately. I've uninstall Xcode 3 when upgrading.

Comment: Well, you can easily grab and install Xcode 3 again from developer.apple.com...it's in the Additional Downloads section on the Mac Dev Center page. You can have both Xcode 4 and Xcode 3 installed at the same time...just install Xcode 3 in a custom folder...I use something like Dev326.

Comment: @ericgorr I looked and it doesn't seem to be up anymore. I just cloned my repository again and it is running... I didn't change any code so it must have been a cache issue when going from 3 to 4.

Comment: It's there...I'm downloading it now. Try this link: http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/5.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.3.3.3.1

Comment: Go to http://developer.apple.com, Go to the Mac Dev Center, Log In with your developer id, near the bottom of the page there will be an Additional Download section...click on View All Downloads, click on the Developer Tools downloads, Xcode 3.2.6 is at the top. If you don't have a Developer ID, get one...it is worth $99.

Comment: @ericgorr Thanks for the link! Although now that I fixed it by re cloning the repo I might not downgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to delete the local project files and re-clone from the GIT repository. Not sure what the issue is, but it may have been related to having opened the project in XCode 4 Developer Preview.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem, resolved:

**Right click your project's .xcodeproj file -> 'Show Package Contents' -> delete project.xcworkspace . The workspace file will be automatically recreated when you open the project again.**

The alternative solution is to create a new workspace (File -> New -> Workspace) and add your project to it (File -> Add Files to "New Workspace"). Essentially the same thing.

Not sure why the workspace file gets out of sync as I didn't go through any Xcode version changes, but I suspect it was related to git commits. Didn't use .gitignore.

---

More info on xcworkspace:

project.xcworkspace saves your workspace settings (Navigator/Debug/Utilities panes,etc) and Editor states. It's automatically created when you create a new project.

From a forum - "When you open an xcworkspace file, it opens the associated Xcode project and restores the perspective. Therefore, Xcode workspace files (.xcworkspace) can be used as a wrapper or container for an Xcode project (.xcodeproj)."

Answer (score 1):

Just cleanup old preferences files from "your_project..xcodeproj" bundle.
In file exlorer right click on "your_project..xcodeproj" -> select Show Package Contents,
and remove all files but "project.pbxproj".
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the zxing ScanTest app. Upgrading to Xcode 4.3.2 solved the issue.